# finding files with most links

Tags: unix, bash, find

how can i find top 10 files in unix with most links to it?

Comment: What links are you talking about? Hard links, symlinks, html-links?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$ find . -type l -exec readlink {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head
```

If you want the number of files shown to be other than 10, then just add the number you want as an argument to `head`.

This will search for symlinks below the current directory, to search over another directory, replace the `.` with the path you want.

Comment: Needs to be find . -type l etc, or whatever directory you want to search in such as find / -type l

Comment: More efficient is -printf '%l\n' to print the link target without having to run a process for each file.  And should the second sort be -nr, for numeric sort?

Comment: Just realized this doesn't really work unless all the links are absolute.  If one link target is foo/bar, and another symlink to the same file is /home/peter/foo/bar, those won't get counted the same.

Answer (score 1):

`find -type f -ls | sort -rn -k 4 | head -10`

Output will be sorted in order of decreasing link count.  (-r = reverse, -n = numeric sort, -k 4 = sort on column 4)

If you want symlinks, then you'll have to look at the other answers.  I answered the only interpretation that has an easy answer. :P

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there's anything about a file which tells you how many links there are to it.

If I'm right, you'll have to search your directory tree for links and sort them by the file they link to.

The `find` command can list links with `-type l` but unless you use find's special handling of links, you don't see what the link resolves to.

So try:

```
sudo find -L / -type l -exec ls {} \;
```

to list links. Then redirect the output to `sort`, `uniq` and so on.

I haven't tested this (it's not complete, anyway): I'm not sure if I have any duplicated links to find in my filesystem which would make a test meaningful.

Comment: This is all about symbolic links. `ls -l` will show you the number of hard links.

Comment: `-exec ls {}` will show the link but not what it's linked to. You can use `-ls` or `-exec ls -l {}` to see the destination.

Comment: Also, `-L` is going to resolve links so `type -l` won't find any.

Comment: As I said, I didn't try it. The idea was to say 'the answer may be over there...'

Comment: -L -type l is the way to find broken symlinks, BTW.